# Flutter android not building release, duo to key.jks issue after moving to new machine

Tags: android, flutter, jks

I have a flutter app not working after moving to new machine
iOS app works fine and published after migration to MacBook, but the android build fails on release only, it works on debug
I recently moved my app to new MacBook Pro and also moved the key.jks to the location at /Users/abdulrahman_karzoun/key.jks but it does not work and shows this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key from store "/Users/abdulrahman_karzoun/key.jks": toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
```

this is the output

also this is the key.properties file

```
storePassword="won't publish password"
keyPassword="won't publish password"
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/abdulrahman_karzoun/key.jks
```

I double checked the the file exists in the location and extension is jks

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I copied the jks file, it got corrupted somehow, I managed to recopy it from original source on old pc and it worked fine